# Need Help in Creating a Responsive mobile CSS using <Div>s

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, centering

I'm working with two rows and 4 columns. Each div contains an image, brand name and price.

The rows are displaying correctly but not centered and when resizing the window the divs should align to the screen size meaning it should go from 4 columns to 2 columns to 1 column depending on the size of the screen.

**I want to accomplish 2 things:**

1. Center the two rows on the page so that its in the middle.
2. Make sure that its responsive; iphone 6 and 5 are priority, followed
       by tablets and androids.

Please help me accomplish this task.

I have a working knowledge of CSS, but don't fully grasp responsive design yet.

My stylesheet looks like this:

```
.row, .row2 {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.col-1-4 {
    width: 260px;
    height: 400px;
display: table-cell;
}
```

*Here is the html:*

```
<div class="row”>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="row2”>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

<div class="col-1-4"><a href=“some-url.html"><div class="span4"><img src=“someimage.jpg" width="260" border="0"><span class="text-content"><span>View Product</span></span></div></a><span class="b_name"><a href=“somebrandurl.html”>Brand Name</a></span><span class="p_name”>  Product Name  <br><br>Reg. Price: $19.99</span>
 </div>

</div>
```

I simply don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You require something like `<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-2 col-lg-4">` instead of `<div class="col-1-4">`

Comment: Hello, are you writing custom responsive css using Media Query. I would prefer to use Bootstrap css framework to make responsive design proper. It is tested over many devices .

Comment: also you may need to correct the HTML inverted commas form `<div class="row”>` to `<div class="row">`

Comment: Kanudo, i guess thee above col styles are in bootstrap . She is creating custom css i doubt ?

Comment: I am using bootstrap.min.css ... but I'm not sure how to connect everything together?

Comment: Did you check out the responsive border less tables at bootstrap... that could be the solution for you

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reinvent the wheel... Bootstrap/Foundation/PureCSS allows you to da that with much more precision

Comment: Believe me when I say I really don't want to...if I am please direct me on how not to because I am using bootstrap.min.css but I'm not aware of how to implement it properly so that I can use its features to do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

You want :

> two rows on the page so that its in the middle.

In bootstrap for responsive design you can do is:

```
<div class = "container"><!-- this will center position -->
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-6"> <!-- this coveres phones and tablets -->
     ... your code here
  </div>
  <div class=" col-xs-6 col-sm-6"> <!-- second row -->
    ... your code here
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `br`breaks any kind off responsive design

if you give me the image of what exactly you want i can better help you.

Comment: I will try this out and update you ... I'm excited to put it together. Keep you posted.

Comment: give me image or rough sketch you want and i\ll better help you